# Simple ajax function send NULL id

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to make simple delete ajax function. I'm not very good ad JS at all but when I click on button delete I can see in Chrome Dev Console that id = NULL and when I refresh the page the entry is back. The ajax function is pretty simple

```
$("body").on("click",".remove-item",function(){
    var entry_id = $(this).parent("td").data('entry_id');
    var c_obj = $(this).parents("tr");

    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        type:'POST',
        url: 'delete.php',
        data:{entry_id:entry_id}
    }).done(function(data){
        c_obj.remove();
        toastr.success('Item Deleted Successfully.', 'Success Alert', {timeOut: 5000});

    });
});
```

And the button

```
<button  class="btn btn-danger remove-item" > Delete</button>
```

And this is the delete.php

```
$entry_id  = $_POST["entry_id"];
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM entries WHERE entry_id = :entry_id"); 
$stmt->bindParam(':entry_id', $entry_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

echo json_encode([$entry_id]);
```

Any idea what can be wrong?

update. The table

```
    echo '<table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Transaction Quote</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>';
        foreach($pdo->query("SELECT * FROM entries ORDER BY entry_id DESC LIMIT 20") as $row){                                                          
            echo '
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>'.$row['entry_id'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['entry_name'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['entry_transaction_quote'].'</td>
                    <td><button  class="btn btn-sm btn-danger remove-item" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete</button></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>  ';
        }
        echo '  </table>
```

Comment: You probably should have some quotes in ` data:{entry_id:entry_id}`, ` data:{"entry_id":entry_id}`

Comment: Can you please show the html table from here you retrieving the id ?

Comment: does alert(entry_id); shows the id?? first check that? and then just keep data : entry_id and in php $_POST['data']; and remove dataType from ajax

Comment: try after remove `dataType: 'json',`

Comment: Add some error reporting in your  `delete.php` code to see any error occur

Comment: Added the table in the qustion

Comment: the `td` element doesn't have a dataset attribute which is what I think `var entry_id = $(this).parent("td").data('entry_id');` is looking for is it not?

Comment: you `td`din't have any `data` attribute so `var entry_id = $(this).parent("td").data('entry_id'); == NULL`

Comment: Thanks for the help to all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your **td** with **class** name

```
 <td class="entry_id">'.$row['entry_id'].'</td>
```

**jquery**

```
var entry_id = $(this).parent("td").parent("tr").find('.entry_id').text().trim();
```

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Comment: Yes, I've marked  it. Just waited for 15min. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Html should be like

```
<tr entry_id="<?=$row['entry_id']?>">
   <td><button  class="btn btn-sm btn-danger remove-item" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete</button></td>
</tr>
```

Js code  should be like

```
var entry_id = $(this).parent().parent().attr("entry_id");
```